# How to check in ESXi CLI if DVD is inserted in to DVD-Drive?

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, dell, drac

I have ESXi 5.5, Dell R430, a DVD rom installed in it. How can I check the most easiest way, if a DVD is inserted into the DVD drive? The reason I want to know this, is that when the system is rebooted, and the boot order is set to DVD, I want to avoid to start any install from there.

Tried to check things in /dev/cdrom, but have not found a working solution yet. It would be okay, to have the boot order check as well, I want to make it automatized in the end - that's why I need a CLI command solution.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just change the boot order?

Comment: While this is a solution, and I agree this probably is the best alternative, you could elaborate this a bit by telling why OP should accept this instead of trying to do some extra verification. Otherwise, this seems more like a comment, doesn't it?

Comment: Hi! Good idea, however it was not exactly the solution to my problem, but it helped. I was able to get info about boot order, which is a solution for me, as I did not need any change, only information about the boot status - instead of checking DVD status.